# Viscous liquid flows through a horizontal pipe of varying cross-section

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

[image: Question with options]

Question:
A viscous liquid flows through a horizontal pipe of varying cross-sectional area. Identify the option which correctly represents the variation of height of rise of liquid in each vertical tube

**My attempt :**
I tried applying bernoulli's theorem :

$P_{1}+ 1/2 \rho v_1^2 = const.$

As all points are at same level in the pipe.

By equation of continuity,

$A_{1}v_{1}=A_{2}v_{2}$

Hence, I got option B as my answer but the given answer is

> option C

Can you please comment what I did wrong or if the answer key is wrong ?

Comment: Bernoulii does not apply to viscous fluids.

Comment: Ohh.. Right It was a silly mistake .. Sorry....

Comment: Can you please confirm that option C is correct ?

Comment: Yes. C is correct. Both viscoity and speed-up reduce the pressure.

Comment: Ok thanks, question solved.